# NavigationLink syntax

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to learn SwiftUI and Swift in general so I'm a total newbie here. I started by reading docs on Swift Language, making a console app and playing around with a bunch of concepts of the language there. Then I tried SwiftUI and immediately I see a bunch of syntax that wasn't documented in the language itself.

So I dug around some more and I see there is a bunch of compiler and language magic going on behind the scenes which makes the syntax I see in SwiftUI work. A lot of the magic maybe isn't so well documented. So I dug around and found answers to most of my questions about the SwiftUI syntax I'm seeing. Except this:

```
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                Text("Select your device")
                
                List{
                    NavigationLink{
                       SensorView()
                    } label:{
                        Text("Raspberry Pi Zero")
                   }
                }
            }
```

What is with the `label:` statement outside of the curly braces for the NavigationLink closure all about? I can see in my app that it creates a label in the NavigationLink but I don't understand why the label: is outside of the curly braces where it looks to me to be more or less detached from the NavigationLink it is seemingly associated with? I'm trying to understand this so I will know when/where to apply this pattern. I copied the code above from someone else's sample.

Any insighgts or teachings would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This new syntax is part of [Multiple Trailing Closures](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0279-multiple-trailing-closures.md), which was released recently. Let's look at your [`NavigationLink` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(destination:label:)-27n7s):

```
init(destination: () -> Destination, label: () -> Label)
```

Here, there's 2 parameters that take in closures: `destination` and `label`. So, that means you can write it like this (the plain, normal way):

```
NavigationLink(destination: {
    Text("The destination")
}, label: {
    Text("Click me!")
})
```

Or this, via [trailing closure syntax](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102):

```
NavigationLink(destination: {
    Text("The destination")
}) {
    Text("Click me!")
}
```

Or what you did in your question. Note: when you have multiple trailing closures, you need to add the argument label (for example `label:`) for all closures after the first.

```
NavigationLink {
    Text("The destination")
} label: {
    Text("Click me!")
}
```

Comment: Except, the first argument is already a closure without having to create a wrapper:  `NavigationLink(destination: SensorView.init) { Text("Raspberry Pi Zero")  }`